# using a resource dictionary in multiple applications

Tags: wpf, dll, resourcedictionary

Is there a way to use a resource dictionary in multiple applications? What I have is a theme generator which uses merged dictionaries etc... works GREAT! I'm looking for a way to reference this project for the resource dictionaries into all my applications. (thus, having my theme engine in every File>New I decide to create) So far my research has led me to nothing.

Comment: Is it too much trouble to just add the project to each new application you make?

Comment: That is one solution, however I'm looking (if it exists) for more of a .dll approach. You know, just point to the .dll, reference the namespace, let simmer and poof! there's my theme generator :-)

Comment: Well you could just add a reference to the DLL of your theme generator.

Comment: But then how do you access the ResoureDictionaries in the App.xaml file and push it down to the main projects App.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I've found out that I can use the pack URI syntax to grab the resource dictionaries from application A and use them in application B

First I made a classlibrary and removed the default class1.cs
Then I added a new item (there was no option for a .xaml file so I added a .xml file and changed the extension)
Then moved the resource dictionary code into that file.
Referenced the new .dll as you would any other and now I can access the resource dictionary file using the below syntax.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source = "pack://application:,,,/App_A;Component/App_A_ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
```

When swapping the files its the same syntax only omit the "pack://application,,," part.
Although this wasn't everything I wanted (so far) it has been the best solution I've found.

The part now that I want is the ability to house the swapping logic within the .dll. If I can do that... then my theme library can be PnP to any app with minimum fuss.